# Class Library Dependencies

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a Class Library that i need to reference in different solutions, and this library has dependencies to other DLLs (itextsharp in this case).

If i want to create two applications using this same DLL (that is created in its own solution), how do i deploy my DLL so it can be used by these?

Do i include itextsharp when i deploy my DLL, or do i state that it is dependant on itextsharp somehow ?

Basically im looking for best practices, or "the way to do it" :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If your application is dependant on the `itextsharp` library and the library license agreement allows redistribution of their DLLs then you should include them in your deployment.

You should leave your application in a 100% working state after deployment.